# How to select all checkboxes without changing var parameters

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I using ViewModel and I have table with checkboxes, I can only check one by one boxes, but I need check all option but I need my var values to be defined, because I pass that values to controller and do something.

```
      $('.checktip').click(function () {
      var idemployee = $('.idemployee').val();
      var idtip= $(this).attr('idtip');
      var chk = $(this).prop('checked');
      $.ajax({
            url: UrlSettingsDocument.Books,
            data: { idemployee: idemployee, idtip: idtip, chk: chk },
            type: "POST",
            success: function (result) {
      if (result.result == "Redirect") {
      window.location = result.url;
     }
     }
     });
    });
```

My .cshtml

```
<table class="table table-striped grid-table">
        <tr>
        <th>Samp</th>
        <th>Id of Book</th>
        <th>
         //Button for check all *(NOT IMPLEMENTED)*
         <button type="button" class="checkall">Select/Deselect</button>
        </th>
        </tr>
        @foreach (var item in (IEnumerable<cit.Models.getCheIdTip_Result>)Model)
        {
        <tr>
        <td>@item.idtip</td>
        <td>@item.tipname</td>
        <td>
        <div class="pure-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" idtip="@item.idtip" class="checktip" checked="@(item.idemployee == ViewBag.idemployee ? true : false)" name="@item.id.ToString()" id="@item.id.ToString()" />
        <label for="@item.id.ToString()"></label>
        </div>
        </td>
        </tr>
        }
    </table>
    <input type="hidden" value="@ViewData["idemployee"]" name="idemployee" id="idemployee" class="idemployee" />
</div>
```

Comment: Hi , can you elaborate more on your issue.

Comment: @Swati My js code doing check of checkboxes one by one and when I reload it was saved and that's ok, but now I want to add `<button type="button" class="checkall">Select/Deselect</button>` to check them all and when I reload It need to be saved all of them. I use this var elements  `var idemployee` `var idtipvar` `var chk` and I pass them to controller and I perform saving in database checked boxes for every employee. So how to do that with passing same var elements but to check all boxes on click feature.

Comment: So you need to pass all checkboxes `idtip` & `checked` status ?

Comment: @Swati Yes that's what I need.

Comment: You can `loop` through `checked` values and then push that values in `json array` try that let me know if you that still didn't work. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65573473/10606400) answer should help .

Comment: @Swati I tried like this but still not working        
           `$(function () {
            $("#btnClick").click(function () {
              var selected = new Array();
                $("#tableLabel input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function () {
                    selected.push(this.value); });  }); });`

Comment: Hi, check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/6c25ujkL/) working example.

Comment: @Swati This is ok but how can I pass this in my controller to save that values from array.

Answer (score 0):

Use check box to check all checkbox instead of button.

On check change, using the class check/uncheck all checkbox inside the table.

```js
$('#checkall').on('change', function() {
  $('.checktip:checkbox').prop('checked', $(this).is(":checked"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped grid-table">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="checkall" />Check All</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="checktip" /></td>
    </td>
    </td>
    </td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="checktip" /></td>
    </td>
    </td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="checktip" /></td>
    </td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="checktip" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I can't pass this code to controller so I can handle code, In my solution I defined var and with ajax data I use it in controller public `JsonResult CheckUsers(int idemployee, int idtip, bool chk)` but in this way I can only check one by one. In your solution I there's no defined variables.